# How to optimize memory footprint of Stanza models

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, stanza

I'm using Stanza to get tokens, lemmas and tags from documents in multiple languages for the purposes of a language learning app. This means that I need to store and load many Stanza (default) models for different languages.

My main problem right now is that if I want to load all those models the memory requirement is too much for my resources. I currently deploy a web API running Stanza NLP on AWS. *I want to keep my infrastructure costs at a minimum.*

One possible solution is to load one model at a time when I need to run my script. I guess that means there will be some extra overhead each time in order to load the model in memory.

Another thing I tried is just to use the processors that I really need which decreases the memory footprint but not by that much.

I tried looking at open and closed issues on Github and Google but didn't find much.

What other possible solutions are out there?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to run a Stanza pipeline on a mobile device and get the models to fit into memory? Are you targeting iOS or Android?

Comment: Hey @StanfordNLPHelp probably I mislead you by saying "app" :) My bad! It is a web app. My code is running in a Python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom line is a model for a language has to be in memory during execution, so by some means or another you need to make the model smaller or tolerate storing models on disk.  I can offer some suggestions to make the models smaller, though be warned that making your model smaller will probably result in poorer accuracy.

You could examine the percentage breakdown of language requests, and store commonly requested languages in memory and only go to disk for rarer language requests.

The most immediate impact strategy for reducing model size is to shrink the vocabulary size. It is possible you could cut the vocabulary even smaller and still get similar accuracy. We have done some optimization on this front, but there may be more opportunity to cut model size.

You could experiment with smaller model size and word embeddings and may only get a small accuracy drop, we haven't really aggressively experimented with different model sizes to see how much accuracy you lose. This would mean retraining the model and just setting the embedding size and model size parameters smaller.

I don't know a lot about this, but there is a strategy of tagging a bunch of data with your big accurate model, and then training a smaller model to mimic the big model. I believe this is called "knowledge distillation".

In a similar direction, you could tag a bunch of data with Stanza, and then train a CoreNLP model (which I think would have a smaller memory footprint).

In summary, I think the easiest thing to do would be to retrain a model with a smaller vocabulary size. We I think it currently has 250,000 words, and cutting to 10,000 or 50,000 will reduce model size, but may not affect accuracy too badly.

Unfortunately I don't think there is a magical option you can select that will just solve this issue, you will have to retrain models and see what kind of accuracy you are willing to sacrifice for a lower memory footprint.

Comment: Would it be possible to load models with mmap? This would speed up loading and minimize memory usage.